# Cannot debug webview with iOS simulator, webview and xcode

Tags: debugging, uiwebview, safari, xcode6

execution suspends faithfully on a breakpoint in webkit's debugger, but a few moments later, the app crashes on the simulator (see attached screenshot). I am using

- Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105)
- iOS Simulator Version 8.3
- Safari Version 8.0.2 (10600.2.5, r185482)

It works well on the actual device.

[image]

Update: Now its happening in the device as well. The console says:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x16d32e00: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   0x2e3ba3d7 <redacted>
2   0x226a5fed <redacted>
3   0x226a36ab <redacted>
4   0x226a39ff <redacted>
5   0x225f0201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   0x225f0013 CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   0x2e3b9183 <redacted>
8   0x31065e23 <redacted>
9   0x31065d97 _pthread_start
10  0x31063b20 thread_start
```